# @ResponseWrapper and @WebResult

Tags: java, xml, groovy, soap, jaxb

i new in JAXB, i just want to know how to call @webResult inside @responseWrapper

for example i want get result response like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <doReceivePushDataResponse>
          <responsewrapper>
          <webresult>string</webresult>
         </responsewrapper>
        </doReceivePushDataResponse>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

but when i tried i got response like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <doReceivePushDataResponse>
      <iniresponsewrapper/>
      <iniwebresult>string</iniwebresult>
    </doReceivePushDataResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

as seen, the responsewrapper does not wrap the webresult, how do I get the response as needed?

i use groovy to create that service, here's the code

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement()
class Input {
    @XmlElement(name = "memberCode", required = true, namespace = "java:financial.sekuritas.pt.com.doReceivePushData")
    String memberCode
    @XmlElement(name = "fileContents", required = true, namespace = "java:financial.sekuritas.pt.com.doReceivePushData")
    String fileContents
    @XmlElement(name = "crc32", required = true, namespace = "java:financial.sekuritas.pt.com.doReceivePushData")
    String crc32
    @XmlElement(name = "urlWS", required = true, namespace = "java:financial.sekuritas.pt.com.doReceivePushData")
    String urlWS

}

@Transactional
@GrailsCxfEndpoint(address = "/doReceivePushData")
class ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService {
    @Resource WebServiceContext context
   /* @WebResult(header = true, name = "iniwebresult")*/
   @WebMethod
   @RequestWrapper(localName="doReceivePushDataWrap")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName="iniresponsewrapper" , targetNamespace="")
     @WebResult(header = true, name = "iniwebresult")
    public String doReceivePushData(@WebParam(name = 'input') 
    @XmlElement(name = "input", required = true, namespace = "http://financial.sekuritas.pt.com/") Input Input)

    {
       return 1
    }       
}
```